# Highcharts dynamic sized custom marker symbol

Tags: highcharts, marker, symbols

I am displaying a chart with a horizontal x-axis, which is a date/time axis reflecting the last 24 hours. Each point in the line graph represents the start time of a 1 hour time interval in this 24 hour period. Not every 1 hour interval will have a point. For each such point, I want to use a rectangular marker symbol to represent the point, and I want the rectangle that is drawn to start at the actual point (the start time of the 1 hour time interval) and always have a width representing exactly 1 hour along the date/time x-axis. Consecutive 1 hour intervals should abut nicely and never overlap or have a space. Further it must be dynamic and redraw with a new size if the x-axis is resized, such as when the window is resized.

As far as I can see, a rectangle marker symbol is not supported out of the box, so I am trying to use Highcharts.SVGRenderer to define a function to draw this rectangle and assigning that function to series:marker:symbol. The function is defined as below. Note that the constant value of 5 in the radius set for marker, which appears to control the values of x, y, w, and h passed to the function. This function appears to work well on initial load of the graph. However, if I resize the window, such that the chart is resized, the markers do not resize as nicely as I had hoped. The value hourPixels changes as I would expect, but not all markers are being redrawn to reflect the new size. If I refresh the browser after I resize, the graph is redrawn and the markers are drawn correctly. Are there any suggestions on how I might get the marker symbols to render properly on resize, without requiring a browser refresh? Or, perhaps there is a different way altogether to achieve this. I have attached a screen shot of what this looks like.

```
function createCustomSymbol() {
  Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.rect = function(x, y, w, h) {
    var startPixel = me.chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(me.chart.xAxis[0].min, false);
  var hour = me.chart.xAxis[0].min + ONE_HOUR_IN_MS;
  var endPixel = me.chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(hour, false);
  var hourPixels = endPixel - startPixel;

  return ['M', x + 5, y, 'L', x + 5 + hourPixels, y, 'L', x + 5 + 
    hourPixels, y + h, 'L', x + 5, y + h, 'Z'];
  };
  if (Highcharts.VMLRenderer) {
    Highcharts.VMLRenderer.prototype.symbols.rect = 
      Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.elipse;
  }
}
```

[image: Line chart with rectangular markers]

Comment: From what you have written, I think using an xrange graph would be easier. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/pzdt540e/. You could then create datapoints like this `{x: point, x2: point + 3600*1000, y: 0}`. That said, if your goal was to change the height of your rectangles based on the data as well, my suggestion would not work.

Comment: Hi Michael Hegerich, I reporoduce your code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1zwmcuda/, but I can not see the problem. Could you refer to the example above and point out how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thank you ewolden from a Highcharts newbie. This is exactly what I need. The version of Highcharts we are using does not support this, so we will need to upgrade.